# Specific Parameter-Passing Styles: Call-By-Value, Call-By-Name, etc

Tags: c, parameters, reference, semantics

Studying for my final exam, and came across this past exam question:

Consider the following program written in a C-like notation:

```
int i = 1;
A[] = {4, 0, 1, 2};

void mystery05(int from, int to)
{
    int temp;
    temp = A[from];
    A[from] = A[to];
    A[to] = temp;
    i = i + 2;
    to = -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    mystery05(A[i+2], A[i]);
}
```

In the table below, fill in the boxes with the appropriate variable values after the call to mystery05 in main.  Each row corresponds to a specific parameter-passing style (ie.  use the style listed instead of the default C-language semantics).  Assume arrays are indexed from 0.

```
style               |___i___|__A[0]__|__A[1]__|__A[2]__|__A[3]__| 
call-by-value       |_______|________|________|________|________|
call-by-name        |_______|________|________|________|________|
call-by-reference   |_______|________|________|________|________|
call-by-value-result|_______|________|________|________|________|
```

I'm not sure on how to go about this, but if it was regular C semantics, I supposed the answers would be

i = 3; A[0] = 4; A[1] = 2; A[2] = 1; A[3] = 0

Comment: What precisely is your question?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to learn how to fill out the table properly with the different parameter passing styles.  Why and how they would differ.

Comment: @Bobby S: We're not going to write out the entire answer for you.  But take the hint.  It isn't "regular C semantics".  Each row is a different semantics, not "regular C".

Comment: @S.Lott: I am well aware that each of those rows are not regular c semantics, that is the point of the question.  Each row is a different from of parameter passing semantics.

Comment: @Bobby S. "Each row is a different from of parameter passing semantics"  Precisely.  Then what's your question?

Comment: Instead of posting your exam question, ask for good book that desribes it. If someone here solves it for you it won't help anybody.

Comment: @S.Lott:  What would the values of each of those values be, if the type of parameter passing was used, INSTEAD of the regular semantics of C.

Comment: @ruslik: Thank you for the advice, but if the question was solved, I would most likely be able to use the definitions of each of these types of parameter passing techniques and follow through how it was accomplished. In my opinion.

Comment: @Bobby: but I have to agree, this exam question is really stupid.

Comment: Look it up. Kind of like a bastard child of call-by-value and call-by-reference -- throughout the function execution, it's call by-value, but as it returns, it updates the input parameter, call-by-reference style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@S.Lott :
I thought 'pointer's to strings and arrays are call by reference. Am I wrong?

I agree: don't want to do all the question. If he has an exam he ought to be more clued up.
I would like to answer the first line though just to see if i have understood correctly.
So I could be wrong!

Call by value:  doesn't change the values unless the variables are global
and in this case they have to be; for how otherwise can the proc make use of i.

Both i and the A array are global.

What happens in the proc changes the values.

i begins with value 1 so values of A[3] and A[1] swapped.

A[3] now 0 , A[1] now 2 . A[0] and A[2] unchanged.

finally i value changed to 3

I think the exam q missed a trick by not asking about the value of 'to' after the proc call.

Comment: Pointers to strings involve a "*" in the type declaration and therefore an implicit "&" in the function call.

Comment: @Bobby S  Wow! Thanks. Very generous. To have got my teacher's badge answering a question I'm still not 100% sure on! Best of luck in your exam. :)

Answer (score 0):

call-by-value  is -- I think -- what you mean by "regular C semantics"

call-by-name is something C doesn't have.  Look it up.  That's not "regular C semantics"

call-by-reference assumes that all the arguments have "&" and the parameters have "*".  That's not "regular C semantics" that's a different semantics, but easily built in C.

call-by-value-result is something C doesn't have.  Look it up.

Each is different.  Don't assume C.  Don't read the code as if it was C.  You have to read the code in different ways assuming different things.

Comment: ... So, why does OP need to look these things up? Shouldn't he already have notes on them? I mean, things are generally on an exam in order to test concepts that were taught in class...